# Generating i18n property files dynamically from db

Tags: internationalization

I'd like to set up a simple server with a DB containing keys and translations for different messages. My different other applications would request this server, which would give them only the list of messages concerning them in, let's say, JSON. The different apps would then "compile" this list into several classic i18n .properties files they could use.

The advantage is that translation service is decorrelated from the different applications nofile has to be re-deployed or even updated on the applications servers. I could even set up a GUI to siplify operations on the messages.

Moreover, I found in the different projects I worked on that the manual maintenance of properties files can get really messy overtime (labels missing for one locale and it's really hard to find which one when the files get big, we used to use a central excel file to manage and generate .properties files but it's just a giant mess).

Anyway, do you think it's a good / feasable idea? Any insight on how to do it? How can I transform JSON into .properties easily? (is there tools for that?) (or should I use another format than JSON?). Thanks for any comment :)

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt, I don't know why you want to reinvent the wheel and make it a bit more square-like.

Is it feasible? Yes it is.
Should you do it? ***No***.

That is, you may serve translations with JSON, there is nothing wrong with that. It often makes sense.

What does not, is to put all the translations in a database. If you do that, I wish the localizers all the best.
It is just way easier to fix the translation in the standard text file (especially if it is UTF-8 encoded...) than in the database.
Talking about translations, you may want to (or be forced) to hire Translation Service Providers. These guys have there own Translation Memory systems as well as Machine Translation systems and guess what? They don't care about your database, nor GUI. They want to handle translations the standard way, that is using typical file formats. Java properties files happens to be one of them. Database scripts are not...

Now, on how to convert Java properties files to JSON. Assuming you are using Java, it's fairly straightforward. What you need first is to read your properties file:

```
// you somehow need to detect a Locale
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
```

The way you detect a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) depends on the context. For instance, you may want to assign one in a user profile (allowing users to change their regional preferences), or you may want to create a web service that take language tag as a parameter. In both cases it would probably go down to this:

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(langTag);
```

Where `langTag` is a `String` containing your desired language tag (either read from user profile, which is recommended, or read as a parameter of a call to the web service).

When you have your resource file read, all you need to do is to take a desired portion and put it to the map:

```
Map<String, String> keyToTranslation = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : messages.keySet()) {
    // filter the key somehow, for example:
    // if (key.startsWith(moduleName))
    keyToTranslation.put(key, messages.getString(key));
}
```

Then you can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert the map into JSON. Actually, any JAX-RS compatible library like [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) would use it internally to perform the conversion.

It is of course possible to do this kind of conversion using completely different technology stack, i.e. using Node.js. However, there are few things to keep in mind:

- Users may have a list of their preferred languages, which they advertise in a HTTP Accept-Language header. It is desirable to return a translation based on this list.
- There is something called resource loading fallback. For instance, you may have no translations for Canadian version of French, but you may have regular French translations, which you may want to return to a user. `ResourceBundle` handles this for you, if you want to use something else, it is good to keep this in a back of your head.

Comment: "These guys have there own Translation Memory systems as well as Machine Translation systems and guess what? They don't care about your database, nor GUI."
True... from the Translation Service Providers' pov! From my (/any) system's pov, it's quite the opposite. Imagine my TSP doesn't work with .properties files but only with excel files (lol), I'm not going to adapt my system to make it work with those files, right? So, I choose a way to store those translations, they work with their system and I'll find a way to integrate their format in my system. [...]

Comment: But really from the (small but still) experience I got with .properties files, it's really hard to maintain, that's why I thought a DB would be more structured (I'm thinking about detecting duplicates and missing translations). When I thought about the GUI it was as a mean for "internal" employees to quickly correct a typo for example, OR for the TSP to have a way to send their files (which I would import , validate and put into my DB).

Comment: However I'm hearing you loud and clear about reinventing the wheel. To be honest I'm also doing this as a mean to learn various technologies such as JPA/Hibernate, 'cause I know that if I were to stick with the DB solution, I would find something existing and much more well written that what I'm about to do. So, anyway thank you very much about your answer, I'll now look at the technical aspect of your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [i18n Maven Plugin](http://basmussen.github.io/i18n-maven-plugin/) to handle internationalization. It's very simple to configure your project. You render different output format files.

- JSON
- XML
- Properties

Check out the sample [i18n resource files](http://basmussen.github.io/i18n-maven-plugin/files.html).